# What is good reference for circle method (Analytical number theory)??

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory

I am trying to read the circle method from  'A Course in Analytic Number Theory by  Marius Overholt.'$\ $ This seems a little hard. any other reference would be greatly appreciated.